# HTML input pattern: all except URL

Tags: html, css

Is it real to set input pattern to all as usually, but with one exception: url are not acceptable. I mean for example all input patterns are ok, but:

```
ftp://example.com
http://example.com
https://example.com
```

we could not enter...

is it real to do without using javascript or no ?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @winhowes accept in input all, except URL's

Comment: Do you need to restrict all urls or just these three?

Comment: @ViktorBahtev all, without js

Comment: why do you tag your question with [javascript] when you don't want it?

Comment: @brabertaser1992 I don't think you can do it without javascript.

Comment: @lupz as plan B only

Answer (score 2):

With JavaScript and using the regex found here: [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url), you could do something like this:

```
function isValid(inputVal){
    return !/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/.test(inputVal);

}

isValid(document.getElementById("inputID").value);
```

**EDIT**

Without JavaScript you can do it like such

```
<input pattern="^(?!((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?))" >
```

^          # start of the string 
(?!        # start negative look-ahead
  .*       # zero or more characters of any kind (except line terminators)
  foobar   # foobar
)

Comment: "do without using javascript "

Answer (score 1):

1. Choose the URL validation regex from internet ( or write your own :) ).
2. Put it in negative look-ahead `(?!)`.
3. Add `.*` for match everything else.
4. Use your new regex in pattern attribute of the inputs.

For example if the URL validation regex is `^(((https?)|(ftp)):\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$` the inputs will be like

```
<input type="text" pattern="^(?!(((https?)|(ftp)):\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?).*$" />
```

**Note**: not every regex will work if you add it in negative look-ahead so just use JavaScript and inverse the result of the original regex. Also your input must be inside a form to trigger the patern validation (on form submit).

Answer (score 0):

The question indicates you already know the regex and just want to know whether you should be using Javascript (or HTML) for this. The answer would be: probably not.

If you are filtering input for - say - a forum, using Javascript would be a bad idea because it runs locally, so the user can easily avoid the check. Use a server-sided language (most-probably PHP) to do the check.